# Object Databases in OrientDB / NoSQL

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb

I'm beginning to learn how to use OrientDB (implementing it in a Java program) and have a couple of questions:

1. If I want to create an Object Database, what interfaces do my entity classes need to implement / how do they need to be annotated?
2. I've read in various places that, even if I start with a Document/Object Database, I can later implement graph functionality. How do I do that? For instance, if I wanted to create edges based on relationships defined in fields of the POJOs stored in the object database, would this involve creating an additional graph "layer" on top of the object database?

I'm in the early stages of wrapping my head around NoSQL in general, so broad-based answers are welcome.